# Continuity of a Functional

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, st.statistics

A certain functional $T$ is defined as:
$$T(F)=\int_{(0,1)}F^{-1}(s)M(ds)$$
where $M$ is a probability measure with support $[\alpha,1-\alpha]$,for $\alpha>0$.
The result that above functional is continuous at $F$, if the measure $M$ does not assign mass to the point where $F^{-1}$ is discontinuous is special case of Theorem 3.7. Robust Statistics by Huber and Ronchetti(2nd ed).

If $\frak{M}$ be a set of probability measures, is there a way to guarantee that 
$$T_{sup}(F)=\sup_{\{M\in\frak{M}\}}\{\int_{(0,1)}F^{-1}(s)M(ds)\}$$ is continuous if none of $M$ assign mass to point where $F^{-1}$ is discontinuous? Is it false?

We can at least say that it is lower semi continuous. Can we say more?

**Details Added:**

Domain of $T$ is CDFs. $F^{-1}(x):=\inf\{y\in\mathbb{R}:F(y)\ge x\}$

**Edit**

The integral should be $$T_{sup}(F)=\sup_{\{M\in\frak{M}\}}\{\int_{[\alpha,1-\alpha]}F^{-1}(s)M(ds)\}$$ for $\alpha>0$

Comment: The question is not clear. What is the domain of $T$? Do you mean by $F^{-1}(s)$ the multiplicative inverse $1/F(s)$?

Comment: @JochenWengenroth, Sorry, I avoided details as I thought the details might not effect the result. I have added details if that can help.

Comment: When you say that the domain are 'random variables', do you mean 'cumulative distribution functions'? What topology do you want on these? (Presumably weak convergence for the corresponding probability measures?)

Comment: @MartinHairer, yes, sorry. I mean CDF. And, also, yes, weak convergence.

Comment: You'll certainly need some additional assumptions since $F^{-1}$ typically diverges near $0$ and $1$, so that $T$ can easily be infinite. This is extremely unstable under weak convergence of the CDF $F$, so that $T$ cannot be continuous if $M$ has support at $0$ or at $1$.

Comment: @MartinHairer, thank you very much for your remark. That was a mistake, sorry. I am in fact looking at the integral to $T_{sup}(F)=\sup_{\{M\in\frak{M}\}}\{\int_{[\alpha,1-\alpha]}F^{-1}(s)M(ds)\}$ for $\alpha>0$

Comment: So, basically, $M$ can be considered as having support $[\alpha,1-\alpha],\alpha>0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you assume is that none of the $M$ assigns mass to a point where $F^{-1}$ is discontinuous then the statement is certainly false. Assume you have a discontinuity at ${1/2}$, it suffices to consider the case where $\mathfrak{M}$ consists of a sequence of Dirac measures located at points that accumulate at $1/2$ from below...